# How to use activities with ViewPagerIndicator?

Tags: android

Let's say I have an `Activity` with a certain content. Now I need to create a new screen with tabs, so that the content of this activity will become the content of one of those tabs. I know I can do tabs with [ViewPagerIndicator](http://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), for example. But, in order to do that, I need the screens to be implemented as `Fragment`s. The problem is that the current implementation relies heavily on the `Activity` hierarchy (lots of calls to methods on the superclass, etc). So, I cannot simply make the current class extend `Fragment`. What other options do I have in this case?

Answer (score 2):

> Now I need to create a new screen with tabs, so that the content of this activity will become the content of one of those tabs

Having activities be the contents of tabs has been deprecated as a technique for nearly three years.

> The problem is that the current implementation relies heavily on the Activity hierarchy (lots of calls to methods on the superclass, etc). So, I cannot simply make the current class extend Fragment.

Replace most of those "calls to methods on the superclass" to use `getActivity().` as a prefix, where relevant.

> What other options do I have in this case?

You could remove the activities entirely and rewrite your UI as custom views. This would be more work than converting them to fragments.

Or, you can just not do tabs.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I cannot simply make the current class extend Fragment.

That sounds like you have a huge Software architecture problem. In this case you may consider a complete rewrite (or more a copy & paste rewrite)

Normally it should be really straight forward to "convert" a Activity to a Fragment.
Fragment has nearly the same lifecycle callbacks:
Activity.onCreate() ---> Fragment.onCreateView() etc.

You can also access the parent Activity of the Fragment by calling Fragment.getActivity().

I don't know your code, but it should be definitely possible to "convert" Activities to Fragments.

You may split your activities code in own classes and inject them to the Fragment.

There is not really a alternative I could recommend you!
If you want tabs, use a ViewPager with Fragments. **DO NOT USE OLD DEPRECATED STUFF like TabActivity**